# Derby plugin not found in pache Derby 10.10.1.1 Release

Tags: eclipse, derby

I have found that in earlier releases of Apache Derby such as 10.8.2.2 the plugin meant for eclipse could be easily found.

There are four distributions listed on [Derby download page](http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.10.1.1.cgi)

> bin distribution - contains the documentation, javadoc, and jar files for Derby.
>
> lib distribution - contains only the jar files for Derby.
>
> lib-debug distribution - contains jar files for Derby with source line numbers.
>
> src distribution - contains the Derby source tree at the point which the binaries were built.

I downloaded the lib distribution which consisted of many jar file but no apparent eclipse plugin. So how can I drop the plugin in plugin folder of eclipse distribution?

Comment: For some reason the plugin was dropped see: http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/derby_plugin_info.html

Comment: then how to use Apache derby in eclipse?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: You can just include the jars in another plugin or even make your own derby plugin